# UIViewController messes up when personal hot spot is turned on

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

When I turn on personal hot spot connection, my layout gets pushed down. How can I either remove this hot spot bar at the top or get a notification for this bar and rearrange my view according to it? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: How are your sizing masks setup?

Comment: From the UIView docs: These properties affect the automatic resizing behavior of the view and its subviews. The autoresizingMask property controls how a view responds to changes in its parent view’s bounds. The autoresizesSubviews property controls whether the current view’s subviews are resized at all.

Comment: Did you got a solution for this? Can we hide personal hotspot when our app is loaded? Please tell me if you got a solution @user635064

Answer (score 5):

When the size of your status bar changes, your application delegate method is called. All you have to do is handle that selector and update your view manually (if autoresizing isn't something you would go with). Here's what you need to add to your app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame (CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame 
{
   // update layout here
}
```

However, as @sosborn has mentioned, it might be a lot simpler to make sure that your views and subviews have autoresizing (aka springs and struts) set correctly (either in code or through the interface builder).

One last note: you can always query for the status bar frame (and therefore size) by calling: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]`